# Fancybox height issue - doesn't cover the whole long page (z-indexes are fine)

Tags: jquery, css, background, fancybox, height

I want to load the fancybox when the page loads. It works fine, but I have an issue with its height. Let's say the page has 3000px height and fancybox has 1500px height. Both should be scrolled down if you want to see the lowest part of the page. Unfortunately, everything works fine, but the footer on the page is not covered by a fancybox gray color. Z-indexes are just fine.
I've tried to fix it playing with autoDimensions, width and height. Unfortunately, I was unable to cover the whole page by gray color around the fancybox.

Moreover, the border where the gray color finishes jumps a little bit. 
Also, the border where the gray color finishes is right above the footer in FF and a bit lower in Chrome. How to cover the whole height of the mail page?
Any ideas what parameters should have a `.fancybox`?

The code below doesn't cover the whole page

```
$.fancybox({

    'width': 620,
    'height': $(window).height(),
    'autoDimensions' : false,

    'content': 'long form with 1500px down',
});
```

The fancybox loads on `$(document).ready()`. `$(window).load()` tried as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to pass an ID or class for calling fancybox? I mean `$('#somediv').fancybox()`

Comment: Try use `$(document).height()`